# iOS: In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, xcode8

I have implemented in app purchase in my application with multiple products and my application is live now.

As i have created multiple products there organization id is eg. com.abc.product1, com.abc.product2 and so on and i have assigned that number according to the id i have received from web service response.

In my Xcode application i have assigned product identifier as com.abc.product and i am attaching that number dynamically to that identifier.

If i have more products to add in the application then i will create in-app products in iTunes connect.

So my question is i need to create new build for those products or i have to just create products and submit those for review.

Comment: No need to create new build, You can add product dynamically but make sure to pass proper product id while in app purchase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you initial app is approved and live, you don't need to create new Build to submit additional in-app purchases. 
You can submit them at any time and submit in bulk as well. See below link for instruction on setting them up

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingInAppPurchases.html

Answer (score 0):

You can continue with this approach. But make sure that you are validating the product identifier with itunes first before showing it to the user, just to make sure that the identifier formed at client side is available at itunes also.